# Windows Authentication between 2 domains without trust

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

We have asp.net web application running on Domain A with working Windows Authentication.

Our customer now wants to authenticate users from Domain B to this website, but we are not allowed to have trust between Domain A and Domain B.

Windows Authentication is not required for the users from Domain B, but Windows Authentication for Domain A should still work.

Does anyone know if this is possible to do?

We are using .net framework 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

what about creating restricted accounts in the domain A for these users?
what about creating local accounts on the server in domain A for these users?
or, you can use Active Directory Federation Services