# IIS windows authentication to other domain without trust

Tags: authentication, iis

I am trying to host a classic asp page in IIS. I have set Integrated windows authentication as an authentication mechanism to access the page.
It works fine.

I have three domains. A, B, C.  A and B both are in trust relationship. C is a separate domain. I have installed IIS in the domain C. I have enabled WIA for the page I have hosted. Windows Authentication will/must check for the user level authentication only in the domain C.

Is there anyway to configure windows authentication in the IIS in domain C, authenticate users against domain A and B without adding it to trust? I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636413/windows-authentication-between-2-domains-without-trust) which is not very helpful.

Comment: You cannot use IIS built in Windows authentication without trust between the domains. But you can write your own authentication modules if you like.

Comment: Yes, I know I can write my own authentication module to authenticate user. But I can't use Windows logged on credentials to verify the user in such case. I want to leverage that functionality.

Comment: Without your own authentication module you can also process logon users credentials if the browsers do send them. Your module just needs to find a way to validate that against a DC in domain A or B.

Comment: @LexLi could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to create an Active Directory server that is accessible by all your domains and then authenticate against it. This design will give you a lot of advantages.

For more details on how to set it up, you can read this article from Microsoft: [How Domain and Forest Trusts Work](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773178(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: Sounds like you misunderstood the question and AD.